# Keep timer running even when user logs off

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a web app on asp.net core. Here’s what I want to able to do:
where a user can login and click a timer to start.
Even when the user logs of the timer still keeps track of time in real time until someone (the user/ administrator) logs back in to click the end button. 
Then I want to be able to capture the start time and end time (in real time)  so that I can calculate the difference and store it.
I know I’m probably going to need some Javascript code to have the timer run in the  browser but I’m not sure how to keep the timer running even when the user logs off. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Your best bet would be to not use a timer at all really, just store the time of the first click and calculate the difference in time between then and now. That way no matter what happens on the clients side (log off, shut down, windows update), you always know how long it took.

Comment: Your assumption is a bit wrong. You can't rely on the client's browser for that, the time can be changed in the client machine to trick your timer. It _has_ to "run" on the server (meaning storing times there). It means you'll have to cope with slight innacuracies due to communication timing between client and server.

Answer (score 1):

1. When user clicks button you send request to the server and save time of the click into the database.
2. When user opens page, you get start time from the DB and start counting from it.
3. When user clicks stop button, you send request to the server and save the etop time.

Of course you have to use it's own id for each timer.

Comment: Yeah but I want the user to see the timer count hh:mm:ss  in real time too.

Comment: @user8964654, doesn't look like a problem for me.

Comment: Does that mean I’ll have to send requests (per second) to the server each time to update the difference ? Again, I want my user to see the time difference  in hh:mm:ss

Comment: @user8964654, no. You send request once and then by timer update value once a second.